# Regex exclusion group for everything escaped (\r, \n)

Tags: linux, grep

I try to make a regex to extract mail addresses from some big text files. Unfortunately the regex also matches on escaped characters. I can not figure out how to configure such a generic regex exclusion group.

Regex:

```
([A-Za-z0-9]+[.\-_])*[A-Za-z0-9]+@[A-Za-z0-9-]+(.[A-Z|a-z]{2,})+
```

Flags: "simg"

Example Text:

```
 <i><b>YudV@lol.ru</b></i></a>
ОМ ПО ЭЛ. ПОЧТЕ: \rCO-O.KI-ES@lol.RU\r.\r\nОМ ПО ЭЛ. ПОЧТЕ: \rCOOKIES@lol.RU\r.\r\n

ОМ ПО ЭЛ. ПОЧТЕ: \nCO-O.KI-ES@lol.RU\r.\r\nОМ ПО ЭЛ. ПОЧТЕ: \sCOOKIES@lol.RU\r.\r\n
```

Regex matches "rCOOKIES@lol.RU" instead of "COOKIES@lol.RU".

You can try it our here: https://regex101.com/r/97ImeS/1

Comment: How do you use it in Linux?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew I use "egrep -RiohI 'regexhere'" to match on all files in a folder.

Comment: And you still get `rCOOKIES@lol.RU`? Not in regex101, in Linux?

Comment: Please clarify, since it is not clear if the text you shared is a string literal or literal text.

Answer (score 0):

Possible solution is the following in case you wanna use python:

```
import re

string = """ <i><b>YudV@lol.ru</b></i></a>
ОМ ПО ЭЛ. ПОЧТЕ: \rCO-O.KI-ES@lol.RU\r.\r\nОМ ПО ЭЛ. ПОЧТЕ: \rCOOKIES@lol.RU\r.\r\n

ОМ ПО ЭЛ. ПОЧТЕ: \nCO-O.KI-ES@lol.RU\r.\r\nОМ ПО ЭЛ. ПОЧТЕ: \sCOOKIES@lol.RU\r.\r\n"""

string = string.replace('\s', '\r')

re_pattern = re.compile("[>\r\n]([a-z0-9.-]+@[a-z]+\.[a-z]{2})", re.I|re.M)
# 0-9 is not required for your example string

found = re_pattern.findall(string)

print(found)
```

Prints:

```
['YudV@lol.ru',
 'CO-O.KI-ES@lol.RU',
 'COOKIES@lol.RU',
 'CO-O.KI-ES@lol.RU',
 'COOKIES@lol.RU']
```

Regex pattern explanation:

[image]